# A question about clopen set

Tags: general-topology

From wikipedia: 
"Now consider the space X which consists of the union of the two open intervals (0,1) and (2,3) of R. The topology on X is inherited as the subspace topology from the ordinary topology on the real line R. In X, the set (0,1) is clopen, as is the set (2,3)."

why (0,1) is clopen?

Comment: Because its complement in $X$ is open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $(0,1)$ is open as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and therefore also open in the subspace topology induced on $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$. The same holds for $(2,3)$. Since the complement of $(0,1)$ in $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$ is $(2,3)$ and therewith open, $(0,1)$ is also closed in $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$. Hence it is clopen.

Comment: ok thanks. another question:

if we have as X=R, then [0,1) is clopen? and why? 

every ball with 0 as center doesn't belong into [0,1). so it's not open.

the  complement of [0,1) is A=(-oo,0)U[1,+oo) . every ball of this complement with 1 as center doesn't belong into A so it's not open, so [0,1) is not closed set.

am i correct?

Comment: @AlfaBhtaBasilopoylos $[0,1)$ is not clopen ... or open ... or closed.  Basically subsets come in $4$ varieties: strictly open, strictly closed, clopen, and not closed or open.  $[0,1)$ is not closed or open.

Comment: @AlfaBhtaBasilopoylos You showed that [0,1) is neither open nor closed. Clopen sets are both open AND closed. Quite a difference ;-)

Comment: Though $[0, 1)$ is often called "clopen", it means more that it's half-closed and half-open. It's not a topological clopen, merely a convenient shorthand for a class of intervals.

Comment: DO NOT use the word "clopen" for $[0,1)$ in $\mathbb R$.  Almost everyone will be confused by that.  No doubt someone once did this, but I disagree that it is done "often".