# Clopen set with metric 1 otherwise 0

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Wikipedia [Clopen set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set) states an example of a clopen set:

> Now let $X$ be an infinite set under the discrete metric – that is, two points $p,q\in X$ have distance $1$ if they're not the same point, and $0$ otherwise. Under the resulting metric space, any singleton set is open; hence any set, being the union of single points, is open. Since the complement of any set is therefore closed, all sets in the metric space are clopen.

The first example is also not to clear but has been explained here [A question about clopen set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875910/a-question-about-clopen-set)

For the second example, I cannot follow the "therefore" logic. To be clopen I expect the complement to be also open and not closed. What am I missing here?

Comment: 'Open and not closed'? You arer under the misunderstanding that is a set  can only be closed or open. It can be both and that is what a clopen set is .

Comment: Some authors say open-and-closed. The definition of a topological space does not forbid    it, and in any topological space X, the set X and the empty set are clopen.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I wasn't, but from the compliment of an open set being closed, it does not follow that a set is clopen. If, however, the compliment is open, then the compliment because being the compliment is closed and open at the same time, and therefore the set itself is also clopen. For a public article, this should be explicitly stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is proved first that, in such a space, every set is open. So, given an arbitrary set $S$, $S$ is open. But then $S^\complement$ is open too, which means that $S$ is closed. So, $S$ is clopen.

Comment: So, now it is clear. Every set means that includes all sets and its compliments. This means both the set and its compliments are open. Thank you. Maybe the Wikipedia article should be improved.

Comment: It's [done](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set#Examples). What do you think now?

Comment: Much better for ordinary people who are not mathematicians. Thank you.